# Запуск скрипта в фоновом режиме

Tags: php

Необходимо запустить скрипт php в фоне через готовую оболочку.

> Схема такая: форма->передача данных->воркер

Все это нужно так как через 60 секунд скрипт умрёт при браузере , а внутри такого не будет. Скрипт парсит кучу данных и заодно обрабатывает, генерирует.
P.S - крон не подходит

Comment: что именно вызвало у вас затруднения? что пытались сделать? сформулируйте, пожалуйста, полноценный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Запуск через форму скрипта в фоне так как через 60 секунд скрипт умрёт при браузере , а внутри такого не будет. Скрипт парсит кучу данных.

Comment: дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> так как через 60 секунд скрипт умрёт при браузере , а внутри такого не будет

У php есть в настройках параметр отвечающий за таймаут. Укажите в скрипте больше 60 сек. и будет вам счастье ([документация](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)):

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Еще можно лимит оперативки увеличить ([документация](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
```

Или вариант через вебсокеты. Можно даже прогрессбар сделать. В этом вам поможет [pcntl-fork](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php) вместе с [ReactPhp](http://reactphp.org). Запускаете [php как демона](http://habrahabr.ru/post/134620/) (например через `screen` или [supervisior](http://supervisord.org)), проксируете через [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com) и радуетесь жизни. Единственное что, нужно написать свой PPM что бы все ядра задействовать. Статья на тему [PPM](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148596/)

### Дополнение

После обсуждений:

1. Делайте запрос от клиента (браузер)
2. В этом скрипте запускаете другой скрипт (например через [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php) или [exec("php...")](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php))
3. Даете ответ клиенту о запуске долгого скрипта
4. При повторных запросах можно проверять статус долго скрипта

Comment: Гмм,браузер держать 20-30 минут. Не очень. Да и хостинг не позволит. Дальше собирать пхп с форком - тоже нет возможности, да и желания. Где-то читал в интернете что можно через команду system(); фон делать

Comment: @МихаилХалупов какая у вас задача? Может хватить сохранение в БД записи о нужной работе, а через крон проверять каждую минуту и запускать php скрипт без таймаута?

Comment: Неплохо. А вообще попрошу вас рассмотреть ещё проще вариант. - system("php -f script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");

Comment: @МихаилХалупов, да, обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Постоянно работающий воркер чем не подходит? Пусть он висит себе, работает, ждёт задач от новой записи в базе данных, появившегося файла в папке, или будет слушать [gearman](http://gearman.org/).

Как только появляется задача - обрабатывает её и ждёт дальше.

Из недостатков – жрёт память даже когда ждёт, может раздуваться. Вариант  периодически перезапускать его.

Comment: По задачам подходит. Но не очень удобно.Поэтому пока как вариант

Comment: «не очень удобно» – где жмёт?

Comment: Удобнее когда нажал, обработал, убился. А держать включенным воркер вечно и ещё перезапускать не прикольно.

Comment: @МихаилХалупов вы видимо понятия путаете. Когда нажал, обработал и убился то это не воркер, а как раз php в самом обычном виде

Comment: @korytoff Я не правильно выразился. Нажал,передал данные,браузер закрыл, пару часов в фоне поработал скрипт и при завершении убился

Comment: @МихаилХалупов так делайте по запросу от браузера форк или запускайте другой скрипт – http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php