# Как сделать так, чтобы длительный php-скрипт, запущенный через браузер - не прерывался?

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который загружает изображения со сторонних хостингов, и делает определенные записи в базу данных. Когда изображений несколько сотен - он прерывается на первом десятке, где-то через полминуты (браузер выводит 500 Internal Server Error). Добавил в самое начало скрипта:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

Но это никак не влияет на результат. Доступа к редактированию php.ini хостинга нет. Запускать скрипт надо из браузера. Возможно ли сделать так (добавив что-то в код, или .htaccess), не обращаясь к хостеру, чтобы будучи запущенным из браузера, скрипт дорабатывал до конца, ну или хотя бы минут 30 ему дать на выполнение?

В принципе, поддерживать соединение с браузером клиента всё это время не надо - думаю, сделать переменную в сессии, которая будет содержать состояние выполнения - чтобы если еще выполняется - клиент видел "please wait" при обновлении страницы.

Comment: 500 Internal Error говорит о том, что в скрипте ошибка. Скорее всего, причина прерывания в этом.

Comment: и ещё добавлю, что из `php` можно менять значения в `php.ini` пока выполняется скрипт. DOC: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-set.php

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics Когда локально тестирую - все нормально проходит, и после того как браузер выводит 500 - судя по появляющимся после этого файлам - он какое-то время еще продолжает работу. В логе апача на это: `[fcgid:warn] [pid 17613] mod_fcgid: process 24327 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL`

Comment: ну дык... а на хостинге и на локальном компьютере совпадают версии php? мне кажется нет.... поставьте на локальный комп такую же версию php, включите отображение ошибок и лечите

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Версии разные, сейчас протестировал на другом VPS - там такое же поведение. Поменял на нём FCGID timeouts - и тогда заработало как надо. Возможно ли средствами PHP решить проблему, не прибегая к редактированию параметров веб-сервера?

Comment: Вот как вы описали в последнем обзаце - так и нужно делать. Отдельным лёгким запросом проверять состояние на сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно запускать второй php процесс в фоне и общаться с ним например через базу данных.

Вот здесь хорошо расписано как это сделать: [Запуск скрипта в фоновом режиме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455635/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5)
Я думаю вам подойдет вариант с http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php или чем то аналогичным.

Comment: Да, видимо придётся делать так. Параметры задержек FCGID редактировать не на каждом сервере есть возможность.

Comment: Даже если вы поставите на стороне сервера over-30-sec настройки, никто не даст гарантии что браузер клиента будет ждать дольше 30 секунд. Потом клиент может пойти погулять или что то еще. Учтите что вам нужен надежный способ общения с фоновым процессом - или бд или что то еще.

Comment: Сделал отдельный скрипт, запускаю его так: `exec("php -q exec.php < /dev/null > exec.log &");` - на локальном сервере работает всё отлично, а вот на реальном хостинге - ничего не работает. Похоже, где-то в настройках php отключена возможность запуска скриптов через `exec()`. Вызов через `system()` - тоже не даёт результата. что можно сделать в этой ситуации?

Comment: Вот здесь в комментариях и See Also можете найти огромное количество вариантов. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Можете попробовать поискать на форуме вашего хостинга.

Answer (score -2):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

или

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Это работает только для cli-скриптов