# Обратится к файлу php и получать от него ответ

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

У меня следующая задача, не знаю как её решить.

У нас есть файл с кнопкой. 
мы на неё нажимаем начинает и с помощью скрипта начинает работать другой файл. Но он посылает нам ответ время от времени пока не выполнится весь.

файл 1

```
<form method="POST" id="formx" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">
<button></button
</form>
<div id='text'></div>

<javascript>
call(){
    подключает файл 2
}
</javascript>
```

файл 2

```
<?php    
for($i=0; $i < 500; $i++){    
$i //постоянно передаём сообщение о значение  переменно $i  в поле файла 1 id='text'   
}    
?>
```

Comment: Нужно что б каждый этап цикла выводило или результат? Просто если каждый этап, то цикл перебирается очень быстро и эти 500 циклов за доли секунды переберет и глазу даже не заметно будет.

Comment: Да нужно, каждый. Ну пусть будет $i = 10000000000000

Comment: И зачем это нужно? непонятно.

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть решение, And.

Comment: @And реальная задача, сведенная до минимального абсурда, который может выложить в качестве вопроса)) а может просто интересно человеку

Comment: Спасибо, DeamonHK.

Comment: Вы хотите сделать, в виде тайм-аутов? Дело в том, что циклы выполняются очень быстро и не сможет постоянно показывать нужный результат, пока не отработает полностью.Если вы хотите видеть, постоянное обновление страницы, вам нужно другое? Например рекурсия.

Comment: Опишите без кода или файлов, кто-чего-вызывает-и-зачем чего именно вы пытаетесь достичь.

Comment: Зачем это нужно?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/321924/

Comment: Спасибо Большое, всем кто откликнулся. Реализовал по своему, но отталкивался от ваших предложений!

Answer (score 5):

Запускайте "второй файл", который делает работу, в фоне на веб-сервере, например через exec или cgi (зависит от ОС/окружения/настроек/разрешений, но в целом выполнимо). [Был вопрос на эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455635/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5), и скорее всего не один. Задача похожа на вашу.

Далее, передавайте значение $i от "второго файла (скрипта)" через БД, или через текстовый файл (хуже и страннее). Например ка каждый цикл $i будет увеличиваться на 1 и записываться в БД (или файл). Когда вам нужно будет узнать текущее значение $i на клиенте и показать его пользователю - делаете запрос к БД (через другой скрипт php) или к файлу на сервере. Так вы сможете получить актуальное значение $i на клиенте, не мешая работе.

Отображение прогресса можно делать через `javascript:setTimeout()` через приемлемый для вашей задачи интервал, 50-500 миллисекунд, например.

Отдельно хочу добавить, что входные параметры работы, промежуточные результаты и конечный результат, а также уникальный номер проще всего объединить в объект "задача/task" и сохранять целиком и БД. Работающий скрипт (worker) будет периодически запускаться и:

1. Искать себе работу в списке не занятых другими задач
2. Если нашел, брать одну, блокировать в БД
3. Делать какую-то ее часть
4. Сохранять промежуточный/конечный результат в БД
5. Разблокировать задачу в БД
6. Завершаться, или запускать новую итерацию самого себя

Это очень общий алгоритм )

UPD: Добавил код простого примера

Файл `index.php`, в примере отображает форму для старта и текущее состояние по задаче:

```
<?php

ob_start();

$html = '';

/* Структура БД
--
-- Структура таблицы `tasks`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Первичный ключ, номер задачи',
  `lock` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Флаг блокировки задачи',
  `input` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Входные данные задачи',
  `output` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Выходные данные задачи',
  `current` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Текущие или промежуточные данные задачи',
  `progress` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'Поле прогресса задачи, будет полезно для сложных многоступенчатых задач',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `lock` (`lock`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
*/

/* Подключаемся к БД */
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'stackoverflow');

$task_id = isset($_GET['task_id']) ? intval($_GET['task_id']) : NULL;
$progress = isset($_GET['progress']) && $_GET['progress'] ? true : false; 
if ($task_id) {
    /* Отображаем страницу данных по конкретной задаче */
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `id` = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $task_id)." LIMIT 1;");
    if ($result && $task = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($progress) {
            /* Если был запрошен только прогресс, возвращаем его */
            $html .= sprintf('%.1f', $task['progress']);
        } else {
            /* Иначе  */
            $html .= '<h3>Задача #'.$task_id.'</h3>
            <p>Прогресс: <span id="progress">'.sprintf('%.1f', $task['progress']).'</span> %</p>
            ';
            if (floatval($task['progress']) < 100.0) {
                /* Также добавляем скрипт для получения прогресса по AJAX */
                $html .= '
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                var updateProgressIntervalId = null;
                $(function(){
                    updateProgressIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
                        /* Анонимная функция для обновления значения прогресса на странице клиента */
                        $.get("index.php", {task_id:'.$task_id.',progress:1},function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                            /* Callback для обработки результата ответа */
                            if (textStatus == "success" && data) {
                                $("#progress").html(data);
                                if (Number(data) == 100.0) {
                                    /* Останавливаем опрос прогресса по задаче */
                                    clearInterval(updateProgressIntervalId);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }, 200);
                });
                </script>
                ';
            }
        }
    } else {
        $html .= '<p>Задача #'.$task_id.' не найдена</p>';
    }
} else {
    /* Отображаем страницу запуска задачи */
    $html .= '<h3>Пример</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="start" value="Запустить новую задачу и запустить процесс работы">
    </form>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="worker" value="Запустить процесс работы">
    </form>
    ';

    /* Проверяем, а не была ли запущена задача */
    if (isset($_POST['start'])) {
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `tasks` (`lock`,`input`,`output`,`current`,`progress`) VALUES (0,0,10000,0,0);");
        $task_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
        header('Location: index.php?task_id='.$task_id);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['start']) || isset($_POST['worker'])) {
        /* Запускаем воркер в фоне. Конкретная строка зависит от вашей ОС/сервера и настроек */
        exec('/usr/bin/php -f '.__DIR__.'/worker.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
    }
}

/* Отключаемся от БД */
mysqli_close($link);

if ($progress) {
    print $html;    
} else {
    print '<html>
    <head>
    <title>ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759003/</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    '.$html.'
    </body>
    </html>     
    ';
}

ob_flush();

?>
```

[image: index.php для старта задачи]

[image: index.php с формой статуса одной задачи]

Файл `worker.php`, проделывает работу по задачам. Может быть запущен в несколько экземпляров, например по одному для каждой активной задачи

```
<?php

/* Подключаемся к БД */
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'stackoverflow');

/* Флаг наличия работы */
$need_to_restart = false;

/* Ищем задачи, которые свободны и не завершены */
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `lock` = 0 AND `progress` < 100 LIMIT 1;");
if ($result && $task = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    /* Блокируем задачу */
    mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `tasks` SET `lock` = 1 WHERE `id` = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $task['id']).";");

    /* Выполняем некую работу (+1 к промежуточному значения в данном случае) */
    $task['current'] += 1;
    $task['progress'] = 100.0 * $task['current'] / $task['output'];
    if ($task['progress'] > 100.0) {
        $task['progress'] = 100.0;
    }

    /* Обновляем и разблокируем задачу */
    mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `tasks` SET
            `lock` = 0,
            `current` = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $task['current']).",
            `progress` = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $task['progress'])."
            WHERE `id` = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $task['id']).";");

    /* Немного отладочного вывода */
    print 'task #'.$task['id'].' '.sprintf('%.1f', $task['progress']).' %';

    /* Проверяем наличие работы в очереди */
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `lock` = 0 AND `progress` < 100 LIMIT 1;");
    if ($result && $task = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $need_to_restart = true;
    }
}

/* Отключаемся от БД */
mysqli_close($link);

if ($need_to_restart) {
    /* Запускаем воркер в фоне */
    exec('/usr/bin/php -f '.__DIR__.'/worker.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
}

?>
```

Пример был написан мной, проверял на CentOS 7 (kernel 3.10.0) + Apache/2.4.6 + MariaDB/5.5.56 + php/5.4.16

[image: Пример выполнения нескольких задач, и как это выглядит в БД]

Comment: Спасибо, wirtwelt. Да, интересный вариант. Можете написать код, как бы вы это реализовали, то о написали. Спасибо!

Comment: Приложил простой пример кода в свой ответ. Можете скопировать и проверить на сервере Linux. У apache должно быть разрешение на запуск исполняемых файлов, а также на выполнение функции `exec` (хостеры частенько ее запрещают, потому что это приличная потенциальная дыра)

Answer (score 3):

Вы пишите что вы хотите чтобы серверный скрипт постоянно передавал сообщение. Это основная проблема в вашем вопросе.

Обычный PHP, исполняемый под веб-сервером, не умеет отправлять ответы по частям с такой гранулярностью, с какой вы хотите. Обычно ответ в части или полностью буферизируется до передачи клиенту на стороне сервера, обычно внутри nginx.

Иначе говоря, вот так просто сделать то, что вы хотите, невозможно.

Если всё усложнить, то это можно сделать. Для этого вам понадобится [изучить работу с WebSocket](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731951/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-longpolling-%d0%b8-websocket/758037#758037), что делает всю схему передачи цифр весьма сложной. Простого примера кода с комментариями для работы по этой схеме предоставить не получится: всё очень сложно.

Другой вариант усложнения: отказаться от постоянной отправки, вместо этого постоянно опрашивать сервер на предмет изменений. Например, так это может быть сделано на стороне браузера:

```
var timerHandle = setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON("my_file.php", function(counter) {
        $("#text").html(counter);
    });
}, 1000);
```

На стороне сервера:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
} elseif ($_SESSION['counter'] < 500) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
}

echo $_SESSION['counter'];
// для передачи нескольких значений можно использовать json_encode
```

Comment: Вот неправда, [умеет](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). Там в примере они строят как раз php файлик, который именно что отвечает с периодичностью столько, сколько захочешь. WebSocket - действительно сложная штука (сам еще пока не пробовал), но здесь, как мне кажется, отлично справится и SSE, т.к. нам не нужно полноценное web-приложение, а нужно лишь получение данных от сервера без постоянной отправки их ему.

Comment: В вопросе написано что "постоянно передаём сообщение", значит нужна именно постоянная отправка.

Comment: от браузера к серверу - ничего не нужно как раз передавать, в задаче я этого не вижу. В обратную сторону постоянно **будут** передаваться через SSE. Читайте внимательнее, пожалуйста)

Comment: От браузера к серверу не нужно, да и где про это в моём ответе, простите? SSE будут работать за nginx, настроенном по-умолчанию?..

Comment: про nginx не могу сказать, нет возможности проверить. Если можете - проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Судя по всему, под nginx действительно нужна еще настройка, чтобы SSE работало. Под apache работает без настройки.

Answer (score 1):

Первым запросом к серверу пишется команда в очередь(RabbitMQ, например).
Постоянно работающий воркер на сервере получает команду, начинает работу, которая выполняет работу в цикле и пишет `$i` в БД или Redis. Дальше по желанию фронта новые запросы читают эту `$i`.

Answer (score 0):

Варианта два.

1. Как уже многие озвучили, самое простое и скучное - писать прогресс в явном виде в файл, базу, другую базу, еще какую-то базу. А самому периодически опрашивать (аяксиком, например) другой скрипт "сколько там уже сделано?".
2. Можно использовать ужасающую и в то же время завораживающую (а главное, нескучную и веселую) штуку - **EventSource**. Собсно как-то так.

Первый файл, основной (назовём его temp8.php):

```
<form method="POST" id="formx" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">
    <button>нажми меня, скорее ;-)</button>
</form>
<div id='text'></div>

<script>
    function call() {
        var text = document.getElementById('text');
        if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
            var source = new EventSource("temp7.php");
            source.onmessage = function(event) {
                text.innerText = event.data;
            };
        } else {
            text.innerText = 'EventSource не работает';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Второй файл, для выполнения хитрых махинаций (назовём его temp7.php):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$i = 0;
$time = microtime(true);
$period = 2; // каждые $period секунд будем отправлять ответ.
// в условии цикла прописано сейчас прописано true, так он будет работать до бесконечности,
// если в явном виде не прервать выполнение скрипта
// вместо этого лучше написать какое-то выражение, исходя из которого
// можно будет положить, что цель скрипта себя исчерпала (уж не знаю, что вы там делаете).
// ну либо оставить здесь true, а уже в теле самого цикла вызвать явно exit/break
while (true) {
    /*
    здесь можете выполнять хитрые махинации, которые собираетесь делать.
    например, можно увеличивать $i, чтобы потом было что посылать
    */
    $i++;
    if (microtime(true) - $time >= $period) {

        // пишем данные
        echo "data: $i\n\n";
        // выплёвываем и сбрасываем системный буфер вывода.
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
        $time = microtime(true);
    }
    // эт просто чтобы тестить, в реале её бы убрать к чертям.
    sleep(1);
}
```